# why ubuntu softwares is not showing some softwares?

Tags: 17.10

Some of the softwares are not shown by ubuntu softwares , which are shown by `apt search` from terminal.
[image]

Comment: Does Software Centre show apps from 3rd part repos?

Comment: I think you should report bug on [Launchpad.net](http://bugs.launchpad.net) with `ubuntu-bug`.